# How can I make all elements work with onmouseover, onmouseout correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My first go at making my own mini webpage from scratch, specifically looking to understand how onmouseover/onmouseout works using .display.opacity. I would like to hover my mouse over each element and it displays text specified text while the rest of the webpage disappears. Hope I gave enough information first time using StackOverflow.

1. my first

   element works perfectly with the function created showHilton().

   however my second

   element and function "showInnovel();" does not

   I currently have 3

   elements and would like this to work with all if possible

```
 <ul>

            <li onmouseover="showHilton();" onmouseout="showHilton();"class="hiltonGrand" id="HGV">Hilton Grand Vacations</li>            
            <li id="hilton" style="opacity:0; background: black; color: white; text-align:right;">hello</li>
            
            <li onmouseover="showInnovel();" onmouseout="showInnovel();"class="in" id="inSol">Innovel Solutions</li>            
            <li id="iS" style="opacity:0; background: black; color: white; text-align:right;">innovel</li>
            
            <li class="DR" id="Dr">Diamond Resorts</li>
            <li id="diamond" style="opacity:0; background: black; color: white; text-align:right;">Diamond</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    

    <div>
        <!--Back button-->
        <!--Home Button-->
        <!--Customer Service-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hilton = document.getElementById("hilton");
        var innovel = document.getElementById("inSol");
        var Dr = document.getElementById("Dr");
        var hGV = document.getElementById("HGV");
        var iS = document.getElementById("iS");
   
        function showHilton() {
         
             if(hilton.style.opacity == 0){
                 //element.style.display = "block";
                 hilton.style.opacity= 1;
                 innovel.style.opacity = 0;
                 Dr.style.opacity=0;
             } else {
                 //element.style.display = "none";
                 hilton.style.opacity=0;
                 innovel.style.opacity=1;
                 Dr.style.opacity=1;
             }
     
         }
         function showInnovel() {
            
             if(iS.style.visibility == 0){
                 //element.style.display = "block";
                 iS.style.opacity = 1;
                 hGV.style.opacity = 0;
                 Dr.style.opacity=0;
             } else {
                 //element.style.display = "none";
                 iS.style.opacity=0;
                 hGV.style.opacity=1;
                 Dr.style.opacity=1;
             }
     
         }
```

Comment: Not sure why my text came out like that above.                                                                    
1. my first <li> element works perfectly with the function created showHilton(). 
2. however my second <li> element and function "showInnovel();" does not
3. I currently have 3 <li> elements and would like this to work with all if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current setup uses a HTML structure like so:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Toggle 1</li>
    <li>Content 1</li>

    <li>Toggle 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
</ul>
```

This makes it quite hard to toggle the next element, whichc would require some js as you've already stated in your question.

I would re-work the html, to something like:

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            Toggle 1
            <p>Content 1</p>
        </li> 
        <li>
            Toggle 2
            <p>Content 2</p>
        </li>     
    </ul>
```

This way we can use native [css](/questions/tagged/css) to toggle the `display` property on the child elements to get the desired output:

```css
/* Hide */
li > p {
  display: none;
  background: black; 
  color: white
}

/* Show on hover */
li:hover > p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="hiltonGrand" id="HGV">
            Hilton Grand Vacations
            <p>hello</p>
        </li>     
        <li class="in" id="inSol">
            Hilton Grand Vacations
            <p>innovel</p>
        </li>   
        <li class="DR" id="DR">
            Hilton Grand Vacations
            <p>Diamond</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <!--Back button-->
    <!--Home Button-->
    <!--Customer Service-->
</div>
```